# I am trying to understand this reading

Tags: power, transformer

So I bought a transformer VC 18/1/16 and when I plugged 240V to from the mains to the primary winding. I then plugged into my voltmeter and it is suppose to show 18V . Does this seem correct on my meter?

Does it mean I need to connect the two tops together and the two bottoms together to get out 18V?
[image]
[image]
[image]

This seems to work
[image]

So I have done this connection and it seems reasonable. I guess I would get 18V if the AC was at 230. Since it is 240V it is showing 21. This seems correct.

[image]
[image]

Comment: it looks like you have one probe on each secondary, so any voltage you read is due to the capcitive coupling between the two secondaries. With the power off, check the resistance between the pins. Measure the voltage on pairs of pins that are connected

Comment: Of you want helping answers, post the **right** Circuit Diagram. So remove the diagram with 2 secondary windings. It is also helpfull to link to the datasheet of the V18/1/16

Comment: @M2T156 While looking for the datasheet, check for the "no load output voltage".

Comment: https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0f46/0900766b80f46e63.pdf

Comment: And what is the no load voltage? Your multimeter resistance is about 10 MOhm, so you can consider it to be no load)

Comment: Yes that would make sense since 18 x 1.24 is around 22

Comment: So that means it's all connected correctly?

Comment: Yes, add a resistive load and you'll see the voltages drops to its rated voltage of 18V

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help. I fully understand now. Many thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90083/discussion-between-huisman-and-m2t156).

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of the 1.71V you measure across pin 2 and 4 on the right side / secondary side:

The outer pins (pin 1 and 4) on the secondary side are not being used/connected. They are just pins sitting there (and being just when you buy the 18/2/16). The resistance of the potting material isnt infinity.

If it would be 115 MOhm and your multimeter's resistance would about 10MOhm, you will read a voltage of 21 V * 10 MOhm / (10 MOhm+115 MOhm) = 1.7 V